# Using twilio sdk for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, cordova, paypal, voip, twilio

I am planing to develop an VoIP iOS app and use Twilios SDK. I am making the choice to either use LiveCode, Appery.io, PhoneGap or build a native Objective C app. I am going to build the app for iOS, Android and HTML5 so the ideal would be to develope in JavaScript for all platforms, but as I understand the support for WebRTC is laking on the iPhone so the alternative for iOS is the [native twilio SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios).

My requirements is:

- be possilbe to use in iPhone 5 with iOS 7 be able to use twilio iOS
- SDK´s voip functionality or twilio´s js SDK (if it is possible to
- wrap a browser that supports RTC in the code?) be able to integrate
- billing such as in-app payment or paypal with zooz or similar
- communicate with REST API´s such as Amazon S3 or a node.js server
- store temporary info in a SQLLite db when app is off line make fast
- and responsive views (file listings etc) is very important
- create cfuuid´s

I have seen several Twilio projects that use PhoneGap but none that are using LiveCode.

I have already built an iOS VoIP app in Objective C, but I want to be able to release it on several platforms also such as for Android and build a HTML5 app, without redoing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a programming question and should perhaps not be asked here.

You can create an external for LiveCode and quickly create an interface using the LiveCode IDE. This is probably a quick and easy way to make a working app. If you're starting with LiveCode but are experienced in Objective-C, creating an external won't be a problem for you.

LiveCode doesn't contain native iOS controls, which means that you have to emulate the GUI. If you use PhoneGap, you also will need to compile a plugin for PhoneGap using Objective-C, but you can use a framework, such as JQuery, to get the right GUI.

Either way, you will have to compile the SDK and you'll need to be quite profound in Objective-C.

LiveCode will meet all your requirements. However, Apple will deny your app if you use PayPal for in-app purchases. You'll have to use Apple's in-app purchasing feature. I believe this is possible in LiveCode now. I'm not sure how easy it is.

I'm not sure about file listings either. On iOS, you won't have complete access to all files on the phone. This isn't a LiveCode limation but a limitation of the OS.